# MongoDb : ensureIndex() - Error : Too many open files

Tags: mongodb

I am in a Windows Server 2012 environment.

When i try to call ensureIndex() for a field of my collection (1 billion documents), i have the error "Too many open files".

```
> db.myCollection.ensureIndex({myField:1}, {name: "myIndex"})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error opening file \"E:\\MongoDB\\base1\\_tmp\extsort.509\":errno:24 Too many open files",
    "code" : 16818
}
```

What is the problem ??

Comment: Creation of a large index can cause a lot of open files during the creation process - you are running up against the limit. You need to raise the limit on the number of open files, if that's possible in Windows.

Comment: I think there are no limit like that on Windows (not like Linux systems with ulimit), so I don't understand.

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert, but the error message is plain. errno 24: too many open files is not just a MongoDB error - it's being propagated by mongod.